# How can I instantiate a comment element programatically using lxml?

Tags: python, html, xml, lxml

I'm using lxml to programatically build HTML and I need to include a custom comment in the output.  Whilst there is code in lxml to cope with comments (they can be instantiated when parsing existing HTML code) I cannot find a way to instantiate one programatically.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`lxml.etree.Comment()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Comment-class.html) factory function. It will return a comment element that you can use like any other element.

Comment: Man!  I tried this a load of times I swear!  It was crashing lxml before but now it seems to be working.  Thanks for the confirmation that it should work.